# Is there a standard place to point people to learn how to typeset their equations?

Tags: support, faq, mathjax, formatting

I've seen a number of questions in which the moderators change html equations into LaTeX, or else people writing in the comments that the site supports LaTeX.  Do we have a standard place where we can point people so they can learn how to typeset equations on the message board?  There is a [short section in the FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation), but it probably isn't detailed enough for most people to learn what to do if they're not already familiar with LaTeX.

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/11305)

Comment: Related: [What notation and symbols are commonly used here?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/740/520).

Comment: I haven't found a link I'm really happy with yet.

Comment: @dmckee I haven't either, at least for explaining how to use mathjax to typeset math and so forth. If you find anything let us know and we can link it in the /editing-help and edit sidebar

Comment: More on LaTeX: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/136/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451 , http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11127 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68388 and links therein.

Answer (score 11):

The folks over at Math.SE have put together a [brief summary of what you can do with MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1).

Possibly the only thing left out for people completely new to TeX-style markup is *emphasizing* that all math is done in "math mode" delimited by one or two dollar signs. (Actually, I suppose `\begin{} ... \end{}` environments are recognized too, but details...) Aside from that and a somewhat dense layout, I think it suffices for showing the basics. Plus, it's already on the SE network, so the MathJax implementation is (presumably) the same as ours.

Answer (score 4):

I found this page in Google once and it is quite good for a very start (it is *short* in the first place -- there is nothing better to convince someone that LaTeX is easy than a thousand-page user manual (= ): http://www.haptonstahl.org/latex/basics_mathmode.php

Comment: This *is* good.

Comment: Unfortunately, this link seems to be gone, though [the Wayback Machine has a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.haptonstahl.org/latex/basics_mathmode.php) (minus the images, unfortunately).

Answer (score 3):

I found the this wikibook very good http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The people at math.SE did come up with [something](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) but it's not really a guide, just a pointer to some resources. I think if we developed a short (but not as short as the built-in help) LaTeX guide here, it would make a great [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question.

Comment: I started [trying to implement this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/806/520), but either mixing code and the MathJax delimiters is a no-no, or MathJax is not active on meta... I suppose I'll delete it soon unless someone objects.

Comment: It's the latter, I believe, that MathJax is not active on meta. I think it would still be a useful reference to have, we might just have to use images to show what the MathJax markup looks like rather than having it actually rendered inline.

Comment: You could ask MathJax to be enabled though. On Math.SE we have it turned on in Meta also.

Comment: @Willie: well then I guess we can try that. I thought we'd asked for it to be enabled on meta here as well but the team denied the request.

Comment: I asked in the mod chat room but didn't get a response...

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I don't know what the situation was over a year ago, but check out http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1 - they've got a pretty good intro guide to MathJax there.

Comment: @ChrisWhite it looks like that question is fairly recent. It would make a great answer if you'd like to post the link (or quote it) here.