# How to input using Latex?

Tags: support, mathjax

I just found this site today and I asked a few questions but I didn't know how to use the latex syntax, so my questions were difficult to understand. Can anyone tell me how to use this Latex program? thanks

Comment: For my purpose, it has up to now been enough to write equations between $ ... $ or if I want them centered between $$ ... $$. Most of the usual LaTex commands seem to work between the single or double dollars.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding on Dilaton's comment:

The site (and most other stackexchange sites where such is appropriate) use the exact same implementation of [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) for Latex markup. Basically, just enclose tex within `$` (inline) or `$$` (set apart equations). Most basic commands work, like `\frac` and `\sin`.

You can also begin some Latex environments without dollar signs. For example `\begin{align}...\end{align}` is a valid construct that will have its contents parsed by the tex parser.

As for how to use Latex itself, independent of this site, well that is a large enough topic to have [its own stackexchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). For basic stuff to get started, try [this other FAQ topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/is-there-a-standard-place-to-point-people-to-learn-how-to-typeset-their-equation). For site-specific abilities, I can think of no better guide than what they have over at math.SE, found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1).

Finally, you can always click the `Edit` button on any post to see how it was written. You are not committed to making any edits.

Comment: The is also [a minimal set of notes in the our FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation).

Comment: It may be worth noting that questions about MathJax itself are actually not on topic on [tex.SE].

Comment: \sin15 or $\sin15$    $\frac12$

Comment: Can you bring latex in comments with dollar signs? $z=e^{sT}$

Comment: Oh, you can ...