# Special text codes for generating symbols

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

What are special text codes that must be written to generate various mathematical formulae, symbols like limit, derivative, integral, closed integral etc. (in simple keypad)

For instance, "**" for italics etc.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451 and links therein.