# How to write mathematical expressions in questions using android devices?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

I posted a question at Physics Stack Exchange site, and I uploaded a photograph of the calculation I had done on that. But, I was asked to write all my calculations in the question(and not in the photograph). So, How to write mathematical expressions in questions using android devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard place to point people to learn how to typeset their equations?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/804/)

Answer (score 6):

[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should work on android devices. You'll still be typing out plain text with `$` symbols enclosing the math.

Comment: To be fair, I think that typing any nontrivial mathematics using the default Android keyboard is a serious hassle --- and I'm an expert at it.

Comment: @rob I'm in India, so the keyboard on my phone keeps trying to convince me that I need the rupee symbol instead of `$`.

Comment: Hmm `€F=ma€` nope, it doesn't work either :-P